# Name Conflict? 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'item'

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, webservices.nl

I am using a webservice (provided by webservices.nl) to extract company data depending on a company number.

```
myserviceBusiness = new nl.webservices.ws1.Webservicesnl();

nl.webservices.ws1.BusinessDossierV3PagedResult result = null;
result = myserviceBusiness.businessGetDossierV3(KVKnr, "0000", 1);

string address = result.results.item.EstablishmentPostcode;
```

VS underlines only "item" in curly red line
Error/ 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'item' and no extension method 'item' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So the problem is that intellisense doesn't recognize item and also streetname.
When I take something else from that message, it works :

```
 string page = result.paging.curpage;
```

the response soap message looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<businessGetDossierV3Response xmlns="http://www.webservices.nl/soap/">
<out>
<paging>
<curpage>1</curpage>
<perpage>10</perpage>
<numpages>1</numpages>
<numresults>1</numresults>
<maxresults>100</maxresults>
</paging>
<results>
<item>
<RegisterLetter>H</RegisterLetter>
<DossierNo>50085980</DossierNo>
<SubDossierNo>0000</SubDossierNo>
<ChamberNo></ChamberNo>
<Legalformcode></Legalformcode>
<LegalformcodeText></LegalformcodeText>
<Tradename45></Tradename45>
<TradenameFull></TradenameFull>
<EstablishmentPostcode></EstablishmentPostcode>
<EstablishmentCity></EstablishmentCity>
<EstablishmentStreetname></EstablishmentStreetname>
<EstablishmentHouseNo></EstablishmentHouseNo>
<CorrespondencePostcode></CorrespondencePostcode>
<CorrespondenceCity></CorrespondenceCity>
<CorrespondenceStreetname></CorrespondenceStreetname>
<CorrespondenceHouseNo>97</CorrespondenceHouseNo>
</item>
</results>
</out>
</businessGetDossierV3Response>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Is this a name conflit problem ? If yes, how can I resolve it ?
If not, how can i extract the data in the results part?

Comment: So the problem is in `result.results.item`. What made you put `item` there?

Comment: ok now it is working, i didn't had to put item there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think item is a placeholder for the array indexer so you probably want to put:

```
string address = result.results[ 0 ].EstablishmentPostcode;
```

Answer (score 0):

The service is returning an array of results instead of a single result.  Use this instead:

```
string address = result.results[0].EstablishmentPostcode;
```

Comment: I think item should be removed from this line. (but i'm not sure!)

Comment: yes that was a part of the reason, why it didn't work in my solution

Comment: Fixed my answer for posterity.